# Can't save changing class object into ArrayList properly

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

I created empty ArrayList of class objects and one class object. I added this class object with some parameters into ArrayList and then changed some parameters of this object. But class object that left in ArrayList also changed. That looks like I'm passing parameters by reference. Also, if I'm trying to create new object and make it equal with "=", that object becoming connected to old one, so if I'm changing first object then second one changing as well like reference to first variable. I've ran into same problem in Java (no surprise). So, how can I pass class object by value? I want to use one class object to add new objects into ArrayList and then change it without changing class object inside ArrayList.

```
class TestClass(var someData : Int = 0)

fun main(){
    var testArrayList = arrayListOf<TestClass>()
    var classObject : TestClass = TestClass(3)
    testArrayList.add(classObject)
    classObject.someData = 5
    testArrayList.add(classObject)
    classObject.someData = 7
    testArrayList.add(classObject)
    print(testArrayList[0].someData)
    print(testArrayList[1].someData)
    print(testArrayList[2].someData)   //Output = 777. Needed 357
}
```

Same with creating new objects

```
class TestClass(var someData : Int = 0)

fun main(){
    var testArrayList = arrayListOf<TestClass>()
    var classObject : TestClass = TestClass(3)
    var secondClassObject : TestClass = classObject
    testArrayList.add(secondClassObject)
    classObject.someData = 5
    var thirdClassObject : TestClass = classObject
    testArrayList.add(thirdClassObject)
    classObject.someData = 7
    var fourthClassObject : TestClass = classObject
    testArrayList.add(classObject)
    print(testArrayList[0].someData)
    print(testArrayList[1].someData)
    print(testArrayList[2].someData)   //Output = 777. Needed 357
}
```

You try to make similar code in Java because arrayList in Java works the same in this situation. So, you can send answer in Java code

Comment: this doesn't really look like Java to me.

Comment: I have no idea what `arrayListOf` does but you are only creating one TestClass object and then you update that object several times. If you want 3 different values you need to create 3 different TestClass objects

Comment: @Stultuske It's Kotlin

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `arrayListOf` exists in Kotlin. [arrayListOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html)

Comment: Then how to create new object with same parameters as first one? "=" makes one class object connected to other. Is there any method that copies all values from one class object to another?

Comment: use `data` class and `copy` method https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying

Comment: Then why is this tagged with Java if it is kotlin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically adding the same instance of `TestClass` over and again with modified value, so the instances in array position `3` will also point to same instance of `1`, if you really want different values, you need to either create a different instances, or use data class with `copy` which copies the values into different instance and you can named parameters to change values you need as below

```
data class TestClass(var someData : Int = 0)

fun main(){
    var testArrayList = arrayListOf<TestClass>()
    var classObject : TestClass = TestClass(3)
    testArrayList.add(classObject)
    testArrayList.add(classObject.copy(someData = 5))
    testArrayList.add(classObject.copy(someData = 7))
    print(testArrayList[0].someData)
    print(testArrayList[1].someData)
    print(testArrayList[2].someData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[copy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#standard-data-classes)

> To copy an object for changing some of its properties, but keeping the
> rest unchanged, use the copy() function.

```
class TestClass(var someData : Int = 0) {
    fun copy(someData: Int = this.someData) = TestClass(someData)
}

fun main(){
    
    
    var testArrayList = arrayListOf<TestClass>()
    var classObject : TestClass = TestClass(3)
    testArrayList.add(classObject)

    testArrayList.add(classObject.copy(someData = 5))
    testArrayList.add(classObject.copy(someData = 7))

    print(testArrayList[0].someData)
    print(testArrayList[1].someData)
    print(testArrayList[2].someData)  
}
```